# getting error when testing a controller using karma in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I want to test my application using Karma . i have configured it and write a simple test suite for checking if a controller is present in my application or not. i am getting the error "Type Error :  cannot call method method 'equal ' of undefined. My test suite condition is given below. Please suggest

```
describe('module present', function() {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('demoapp'));
    it('should have a demoCtrl controller', function() {
        expect(demoapp.ProductCtrl).not.to.equal(null);
    });
});
```

my karma.config is like this

```
 files : [
      'Scripts/angular.js',
      'Scripts/angular-translate.js',
      'Scripts/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',
      'Scripts/angular-mocks.js',
      'Scripts/angular-*.js',
      'Test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
      'Scripts/ProjectScript/app.js',
      'Scripts/ProjectScript/DemoData.js',
      'Scripts/ProjectScript/TimerController.js',     
      'Scripts/ProjectScript/**/*.js',
      'Test/unit/**/*.js'

    ],

    exclude : [
      'Scripts/angular-loader.js',
      'Scripts/angular-scenario.js'
    ],
```

Thanks and regards
utpal

Comment: Show us your karma.conf.js

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo karma.config file is mentioned above.

Comment: not quite sure. but if you are useing jasmine it should be .toBe(null) and not not.to.equal(null)

Comment: Indeed, I think the right methods are `toEqual()` and `toBe()`

Comment: @glepretre and michael yes you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, i hope it helps

```
beforeEach(module('demoapp'));

  var ctrl, scope;
  // inject the $controller and $rootScope services
  // in the beforeEach block
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // Create the controller
       ctrl = $controller('ProductCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

it('should have a demoCtrl controller', function() {
        expect(ctrl).not.to.equal(null);
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but it is returning undefined instead of null because when I am writing the below test specification it is giving the undefined error.                                  it('should check name', function() {
    expect(scope.name).toBe("utpal");
  });

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are showing your entire karma.conf.js file. At any rate, you should mention the testing framework you want to use in the configuration. You need a attribute saying

```
frameworks: ["jasmine"]
```

The following is an example of an entire configuration. This works perfectly.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basepath: '.',
        frameworks: ["jasmine"],
        //list of file patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'web/public/lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js',
            'web/public/lib/angular/angular.min.js',
            'web/public/lib/async/async.js',
            'test/client/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
            'web/public/lib/angular-ui/*.js',
            'web/public/js/**/*.js',
            'test/client/public/js/**/*.js',
            'test/client/public/js/**/*.coffee'
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            'web/public/js/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
            '**/*.coffee': ['coffee']
        },

        // use dots reporter, as travis terminal does not support escaping sequences
        // possible values: 'dots' || 'progress'
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

        coverageReporter: {
            type: 'lcov',
            dir: 'coverage/'
        },

        // these are default values, just to show available options

        // web server port
        port: 8089,

        // cli runner port
        runnerPort: 9109,

        //urlRoot = '/__test/';

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: false,

        // polling interval in ms (ignored on OS that support inotify)
        autoWatchInterval: 0,

        // Start these browsers, currently available:
        // - Chrome
        // - ChromeCanary
        // - Firefox
        // - Opera
        // - Safari
        // - PhantomJS
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
        singleRun: true

    });
};
```